# Is taking the address of a member of an uninitialized object well defined?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, object-lifetime, ctor-initializer, member-access

Consider the following example. When `bar` is constructed, it gives it's base type (`foo`) constructor the address of `my_member.y` where `my_member` is data member that hasn't been initialized yet.

```
struct foo {
    foo(int * p_x) : x(p_x) {}
    int * x;
};

struct member {
    member(int p_y) : y(p_y) {}
    int y;
};

struct bar : foo
{
    bar() : foo(&my_member.y), my_member(42) {}
    member my_member;
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    bar my_bar;
    std::cout << *my_bar.x;
}
```

Is this well defined? Is it legal to take the address of an uninitialized object's data member? I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996855/reference-to-uninitialized-object-iniside-constructor) about passing a reference to an uninitialized object but it's not quite the same thing. In this case, I'm using the [member access operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_member_access_operators) `.` on an uninitialized object.

It's true that the address of an object's data member shouldn't be changed by initialization, but that doesn't necessarily make *taking* that address well defined. Additionally, the ccpreference.com page on [member access operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_member_access_operators) has this to say :

> The first operand of both operators is evaluated even if it is not necessary (e.g. when the second operand names a static member).

I understand it to mean that in the case of `&my_member.y` `my_member` would be evaluated, which I believe is fine (like `int x; x;` seems fine) but I can't find documentation to back that up either.

Comment: It is definitely well defined. And built-in address of operator does not access member storage. The given quote refers only to `.` and `->` operators.

Comment: @VTT Then I guess what I'm asking is if using `.` in `&my_member.y` is well defined.

Comment: Ohh, so I guess the issue with `&my_member.y` is not actually address of operator, but rather member access operator that evaluates the still-not initialized object. I should've read question more carefully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First let's make accurate the question.

What you are doing isn't using an uninitialized object, you are using an object not within its lifetime. `my_member` is constructed after `foo`, therefore the lifetime of `my_member` hasn't begun in `foo(&my_member.y)`.

From [[basic.life]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.life#7)

> before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated [...], any glvalue that refers to the original object may be used but only in limited ways. [...] such a glvalue refers to allocated storage, and using the properties of the glvalue that do not depend on its value is well-defined. The program has undefined behavior if:
>
> - the glvalue is used to access the object, or [...]

Here accessing it means specifically to either read or modify the value of the object.

The evaluation of `my_member` yields a lvalue, and there is nothing necessitating a conversion to prvalue, hence it stays a lvalue. Likewise, the evaluation of `my_member.y` is also a lvalue. We then conclude that no object's value have been accessed, this is well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are allowed to pass `&my_member.y` to `foo`'s constructor, and even copy the pointer - which you do with `x(p_x)`.

The behaviour on *dereferencing* that pointer though in `foo`'s constructor is undefined. (But you don't do that.)